# What is my function supposed to call?

Tags: c++, function, class, templates, abstract-data-type

So I have a class defined as such

```
template<class ItemType>
class Bag : public BagInterface<ItemType>
{
 public:
  Bag();
  Bag(const ItemType &an_item); // contrusctor thats constructs for a signal item.
  int GetCurrentSize() const;
  bool IsEmpty() const;
  bool Add(const ItemType& new_entry);
  bool Remove(const ItemType& an_entry);
  void Clear();
  bool Contains(const ItemType& an_entry) const;
  int GetFrequencyOf(const ItemType& an_entry) const;
  vector<ItemType> ToVector() const; 

 private:
  int GetIndexOf(const ItemType& target) const;   
  static const int kDefaultBagSize_ = 6;  
  ItemType items_[kDefaultBagSize_]; // array of bag items
  int item_count_;                    // current count of bag items 
  int max_items_;                 // max capacity of the bag
```

and my professor specifically ask that we use the function

```
 void DisplayBag(const Bag<ItemType> &a_bag);
```

to display a contents in a bag, problem is that I have no idea how to get it to work.
For example, in my int main i have

```
Bag<string> grabBag;
grabBag.Add(1);
Display(grabBag);
```

then in my display function I have.

```
void DisplayBag(const Bag<ItemType> &a_bag)
{
    int j = 6;
    for(int i = 0; i < j; i++)
    {
        cout << a_bag[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

I tried messing with this code in multiple ways and nothing works. I have

```
void DisplayBag(const Bag<ItemType> &a_bag);
```

Declared before my int main() and the function itself it written in the same header file of the class implementation.

vector function

```
template<class ItemType>
vector<ItemType> Bag<ItemType>::ToVector() const
{
  vector<ItemType> bag_contents;
  for (int i = 0; i < item_count_; i++)
    bag_contents.push_back(items_[i]);
  return bag_contents;
}  // end toVector
```

Comment: This class definition seems suspect; why would `Bag` have a method for displaying *another* `Bag`?

Comment: Are you sure `DisplayBag` isn't meant to be `static`?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: Note the use of the word "professor".

Comment: If you want `grabBag` to display its own contents, then according to the interface you could call `grabBag.Display(grabBag);`. Yes, this is a bit strange, but you have a strange interface (as noted in previous comments).

Comment: @DavidK, I now realize that I was not suppose to add the displaybag() function in the class. But now I dont know what to do next. So are all my contents in grabBag in a_bag? I can't seem to call anything from it.

Comment: Since `a_bag` is declared by `const Bag<ItemType> &a_bag`, the only functions of it that you can call are the ones that are declared `const`, such as `bool IsEmpty() const;`. You can't compile `a_bag[i]` because you have not defined a function such as `operator[](int)` for `Bag` (unless it's somehow defined in `BagInterface`, which seems unlikely).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to display the contents of a `Bag`, the function `DisplayBag` must be able to find out what the contents *are*. The only function I see by which it can do that is `vector<ItemType> ToVector() const;`. Once you have gotten a `vector<ItemType>` from this function you should be able to display the data by iterating through the elements of the `vector<ItemType>`. (You *will* be able to use the `[i]` syntax then because `vector` defines `operator[]`.)

Of course in the meantime you have had to make an extra copy of everything in the `Bag` in a new data structure merely in order to display it.

I sincerely hope that the purpose of this exercise is to give you an object lesson in
the consequences of bad interface design, and that your professor has plans to show
you later how this interface *should* be written.

Comment: Unfortunately, experience leads me to believe that the professor probably won't teach how to do it properly later.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Most of this stuff is very new to me and I haven't been taught what exactly are templates and haven't gotten enough experience with constructors. So am I suppose to do `grabBag.ToVector();` then `DisplayBag(grabBag)`? I tried this and the `operator[]` is still undefined.

Comment: Okay so I managed to get it working by declaring `vector<string> someVector = grabBag.ToVector();` and then `DisplayBag(someVector);` but I had to change my initial `void DisplayBag(const Bag<ItemType> &a_bag);` to 
`void DisplayBag(const vector<ItemType> &a_bag);` anyway to keep it as a bag?

Comment: Nevermind, I solved it by adding a `vector<string> new_vector = a_bag.ToVector();` into my display function. Thanks for everything!